# How many Neurons are in a single Layer Transformer?

Tags: transformer, architecture, neurons

For example, in the base model described in the original paper, each layer has the following configuration:

- 6 layers in the encoder
- 6 layers in the decoder
- A model size (i.e., the dimension of the embeddings and the hidden layers) of 512
- 8 attention heads
- A feed-forward/filter size of 2048

How do I calculate the number of Neurons? Is there any formula, as in the parameters?